# Postgres storing and retrieving double quotes

Tags: postgresql

I am storing data which includes single and double quotes in a column which has a type of text.

I have a function that returns that column but it always returns the double quote character being doubled up. I tried to escape the character \" but that just returned \"". I have the same process working in MySQL well. I am trying to move to Postgres for greater scaling and stability but it seems it does not work well. I have noticed in pgAdmin when I look at the data output, it seems to show the data correctly so I am wondering what is being done there for it to work correctly?

Also I am getting a (" at the start of the returned value and ") at the end.

Can someone help please?

Comment: What language do you use? Wich framework? Can you give more information or share the function you mentioned?

Comment: Also please provide some actual data, results (as [formatted text](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) - **no images**), and queries you have tried.

Comment: Postgres does not duplicate them and in SQL there is no need to escape double quotes. This is something in your application code that does this. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=48cc8f8ca68fee1460c2c7b6822a59c6

Comment: Welcome! As others already pointed out good ... pointers, I wanted to touch on `scaling`. Do you only plan to increase read capacity but not compute? In other words, if you foresee a need for sharding in the next 5 years, I strongly suggest a sharded cluster such as MariaDB. It is also much closer to MySQL and will cost less in migration/training, too.

Comment: I am using php with postgreq, I hard code - no frameworks.
FUNCTION public.getpage(integer)
    RETURNS page  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE    
    COST 100
AS $BODY$declare 
inPage alias for $1;
outPage page;
BEGIN
select into outPage 
components_main.compdoc||components_content.compcontent||components_main.compbodyf 
from framework left join components_main on components_main.cid=framework.bodyid 
left join components_content on components_content.cid=framework.contentid 
where framework.cid = inPage;
return outPage;
end;$BODY$;

Comment: Output from query snipet:

("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head><meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html; charset=UTF-8>   
<div class=""row"">
  <div class=""col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3"">
    <div class=""panel panel-default"">
   <div class=""panel-heading text-center"">
...
 </div> </body> </html>")
I have trimmed it down. But you can see the doubling of double quotes and the extra (" ") surrouding the entire output.

Comment: I think you can try to use pg_escape_string to save your data in PostgreSQL. 
Another (not good) solution can be use a replace function in your string:
$outPage = str_replace('""', '"', $outPage);

Answer (score 1):

Use [pg_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) to escape quote characters in your string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the data is not the issue. I have tried running the same query that is within the Function directly rather than using the stored function and my data is returned perfectly. So my thought is that the stored Function seems to apply strange processing on the way out to give php a result which is doubling the double quotes and adding those pesky (" ") at the start and finish. Any ideas?